# How to make multiple lists equal to multiple other lists

Tags: python, string, for-loop, syntax-error, eval

I will have an arbitrary number of lists, 3 given here for example. I want to make these three lists equal to other three lists.

```
L1 = [1,1,1]
L2 = [2,2,2]
L3 = [3,3,3]
#and
changedL1 = [4,4,4]
changedL2 = [5,5,5]
changedL3 = [6,6,6]
```

Desired result:

```
L1 = [4,4,4]
L2 = [5,5,5]
L3 = [6,6,6]
```

What I have tried so far:

```
for I in range(0,4):
  eval(f'L{i}') = eval(f'changedL{i}')
```

Error message received:
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: "make these three lists equal to other three lists" - why not just copy the required lists?

Comment: can you just deepcopy the three lists?

Comment: I don't think that it will be possible to use copy methods. I am just presenting a simplified snippet of the entire code but I need the original list to be modified

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it using [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) to get the local symbol table:**

```
L1 = [1,1,1]
L2 = [2,2,2]
L3 = [3,3,3]
#and
changedL1 = [4,4,4]
changedL2 = [5,5,5]
changedL3 = [6,6,6]

variables = locals()

for I in range(1,4):
  variables[f'L{I}'] = variables[f'changedL{I}']

print(L1, L2, L3)
```